# Mysql order post by most recent activity count

Tags: mysql

I have two table in mysql Post table and post_activity table 
Post table as follows

```
  Post_Id         Post               Post_Date         
-----------------------------------------------                       
    1           sample post 1       2015-05-01
    2           sample post 2       2015-06-01
    3           sample post 3       2015-06-02
-----------------------------------------------
```

These posts are displayed in a page, users can view,comment and like  these posts, these activities are stored in  post_activity table as follows

```
 Act_id       Post_Id      Activity       Act_date
-----------------------------------------------------
   1            1           commented      2015-07-01
   2            1           viewed         2015-07-01
   3            2           viewed         2015-07-01
   4            2           viewed         2015-07-01
   5            2           liked          2015-07-01
   6            2           commented      2015-07-01
   7            1           viewed         2015-07-02
   8            3           viewed         2015-07-03
   9            3           commented      2015-07-03
   10           2           viewd          2015-07-03
   11           2           commented      2015-07-03
   12           2           viewd          2015-07-03
   13           1           viewd          2015-07-03
 -----------------------------------------------------
```

I want to display posts by most recent activity count on the day user visit the page if no activity then it will display based on previous day activity and so on
result example as follows

when visiting website on 02-07-2015 posts will display in the following order

```
   Sample Post 1
   Sample Post 2
   Sample Post 3
```

because activity done on 02-07-2015 only on post1 so it come first, remaining come based on previous date activity count

when visiting website on 03-07-2015 posts will display in the following order

```
   Sample Post 2
   Sample Post 3
   Sample Post 1
```

because most activity done on 03-07-2015 on post2 so it come first,next most activity don on post 3 so it come 2nd etc

when visiting website on 04-07-2015 posts will display in the order of 03-07-2015 since no activity done on 04-07-2015

Advise me to write best mysql select query to get this desired output

Comment: I don't understand the phrase 'activity count'. Don't you just mean 'most recent activity' ??

Comment: activity count means total no of activity ( total no of comments+ no of likes + no of viewers) on aperticular date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below query

```
    select post,act_date from
    (
    select post,act_date,count(*) as cnt
    from post p inner join post_Activity pa on pa.post_id = p.post_id
    group by act_date,post_id
    ) t
    order by act_date desc,cnt asc
```

Comment: it give result in the order of act_date only. i need posts that have most activity on a particular date

Comment: you mean by "posts that have most activity" is posts that have maximum activity count or  post that have most recent activities??

Comment: @user27 : post that have maximum activity on most recent date will come first

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer but hope it will be a guidance.

The query below will count the number of activities (viewed, liked, ...) done on a post and order according that count and display according to a certain date (the day user visit the page)

```
SELECT  `post`.`post` , COUNT(  `post_activity`.`post_id` ) AS  'number_of_act_on_post'
FROM  `post` 
LEFT JOIN  `post_activity` ON  `post`.`post_id` =  `post_activity`.`post_id` 
WHERE  `post_activity`.`act_date` =  '2015-07-03' 
GROUP BY  `post_activity`.`post_id` 
ORDER BY  `number_of_act_on_post` DESC
```

as you can see, your expected outcome for the date '2015-07-03' can be achieved with above query. But for '2015-07-02' it will output only one record (sample post 1) since there is only one record at that date. Also for dates like '2015-07-04' the query will return an empty results since there are no records under that date in 'post_activity' table. If you can sort out this two issues then you have your answer.